# How to delete a row where the name of the row is with '.'

Tags: postgresql

I have this table:

```
 id |            key            |                value                 
----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------
  1 | insight.enabled           | true
  3 | customer_id               | 2720f38b-c999-4f29-ba32-4da851c58d06
  4 | eula_accepted             | true
  5 | insight.mandatory_confirm | true
  6 | automation.enabled        | true
  7 | automation.enabled        | false
  8 | automation.enabled        | false
```

And I want to delete automation.enabled row , when I perform the following command:

```
delete from configuration where automation.enabled='false';
```

I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "automation"
LINE 1: delete from configuration where automation.enabled='false';
```

How can I escape the '.' as part of the column name ?

Comment: `automation.enabled` is a column _value_, not a name. The column name is `key`

Comment: automation.enabled is the column name actually.

Comment: No, your sample data clearly shows it's a value inside a column named `key`

Answer (score 0):

The condition requires a column. `automation.enabled` is a value within a particular row. Hence, what you need is this:

```sql
DELETE from configuration where key = 'automation.enabled' AND value = 'false';
```